# How do I use desktop notifications in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I tried running this function, but nothing happens;

```
function notify() {
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
      '',
      'title',
      'this is the message'
    );
    notification.show();
}
```

I couldnt find anything on google about desktop notification in google apps script,
so here I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification() in the web notifications API has been deprecated. check out the documentation for more details [Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the [GAS Browser class (Browser.msgBox())](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser) for standard message boxes or ["toast"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast%28String,String,Number%29) - cute little pop-ups - within spreadsheets.